# Workbook sharing vb.net

Tags: excel, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I have a windows application form created in visual studio 2013. I need to enter data from form to excel sheet until the users close the form. The workbook will be shared by multiple users at the same time. Moreover, I do not want them to see the workbook unless they open it.

How do I do this?

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\1.xlsx")
    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim alpha As Long = 0
    iRow = 5
    With xlWorkSheet
        Do While .Cells(iRow, 2).value <> ""
            iRow = iRow + 1
        Loop

        .Cells(iRow, 2).Value = t1.Text
        .Cells(iRow, 3).Value = t2.Text
        .Cells(iRow, 5).Value = t3.Text
    End With
    xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
    xlWorkBook.Save()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this:

```
xlApp.Visible=False
```